# Azure DevOps - How to allow a build agent to run a limited set of tasks

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

We have a set of privileged operations which we would like to secure. We are considered pulling up a custom build agent and deploy the privileged operations to this agent. Which custom tasks a Azure Pipelines user would be able to execute these operations. It should not be allowed to run arbitrary custom scripts through pipeline tasks such as the Az Cli task, or PowerShell task.

Microsoft is stating in the documentation that it is possible to control the available tasks for a custom build agent. Refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/security/misc?view=azure-devops#control-available-tasks

Unfortunately the documentation is not clear on how this can be configured.
How can I configure this?

Answer (score 0):

You can set it on organization level in the `Settings` tab

[image]

Comment: So you cannot scope it by custom agent? It is not very useful if you need to manage two orgs, with duplicate projects with two sets of Azure Pipeline collections.